# err: file '/lib/libgcc_s.so.1' not found

Tags: vmware, shared-library

I'm running 32bit ubuntu in a virtual machine inside vmplayer. That file simply doesn't exist, what do I do?

Comment: It would be better if you explain what action that you do gives an error related to that library. Also, it would be better to know what version of ubuntu you are using, because things related to that library are very different between maverick and natty, for example.

Comment: yshu7s response reminds me of some tools, which you had to run on installation - maybe not the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my VMware Workstation (not vmplayer),
I found them at `/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1/libgcc_s.so.1` and `/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1/libgcc_s.so.1`